# htaccess rewrite rule - url param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is probably incredibly simple, but I've gone through several links and can't find the answer that I'm looking for.

My URL:

www.website.org/shows/index.php?id=1

Desired Rewrite:

www.website.org/shows/id/index.php

I know I need to use the `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` for Apache, I just can't figure out how to get it to match then rewrite.

My failed attempt:

```
RewriteRule ^/shows/index.php?id=([0-9])$ shows/$1/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule should be like that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^shows/index\.php$ /shows/%1/index.php
```

There is a very good official documentation, which explains how to access quesry sting in rewrite rules: https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! And thank you 10x over for the very helpful link!!! Many thanks!!